# Could not determine the dependencies of task ':google_maps_flutter:compileDebugAidl'

Tags: flutter

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':google_maps_flutter:compileDebugAidl'.
> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':google_maps_flutter:debugCompileClasspath'.
   > Could not find com.google.android.gms:play-services-screens.maps:17.0.0.
     Required by:
         project :google_maps_flutter

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 24s
Finished with error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

I am getting this error, I changed flutter channel, run flutter clean, remove ^ before package version but didn't work.

```
google_maps_flutter: ^0.5.21+15
```

How to fix?

Comment: try `flutter clean` then `flutter pub` get and finally run your project

Comment: you mean `flutter pub get`? I did that so many times but no luck. I have no idea what is the reason I didn't change anything in my code. I run and see this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It fixed after deleting `~/.pub-cache`